# Как узнать ID формы из элемента находящегося в ней?

Tags: jquery, html, form

Всем привет.

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.

Сейчас у меня так

```
$(elem).get(0).form.id;
```

В elem указано id Поля формы.
Но вот если туда подставляю ID не поля, а дива, то мне не находит id формы.

Каким образом можно получать id формы из любого ее элемента, если есть только его id?

У меня несколько форм, которые работают с одним и тем же JS скриптом.
Т.е. фактически там различия могут быть только в ID формы, а могут и быть разные поля, а может быть вообще все одинаковое.

Каждое поле формы, если было изменено, то срабатывает onclick, который отсылает ID поля в обработчик. И вот по этому ID нужно получать ID той формы в которой этот onclick сработал.
Но есть элементы, где мне нужно НЕ id поля, а ID дива отправить. И вот тут не могу понять как сделать.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно найти ближайший родительский элемент с помощью [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) и получить его ID с помощью [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
var formId = $(elem).closest('form').attr('id');
```

Comment: Вот спасибо.

Comment: @drop_off, да без проблем :)